# How to add Bootstrap Date Picker as Ember Component

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

One of the things I struggle the most with is taking existing libraries and adding them to my Ember project. I am currently trying to add the [Bootstrap Date Picker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as an Ember component but I can not get it to behave correctly.

I have added the Bootstrap JS files to my Vendor folder and added the following to ember-cli-build:

```
app.import('vendor/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js');
```

Then I have created a component pod called date_picker. The template for the component is as follows:

```
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JS file for the component is currently:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({

addDate(){
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    startDate: '-3d',
    autoclose: true
});
}
});
```

The component is called in the main template with `{{date-picker}}`. The above does render a date picker on the screen but one that does not behave correctly. It does not auto close for example and whilst the format is correct, it does not go cycle through months or always select the correct date on a button click.

Is there a step I have missed in integrating this into an Ember project?

Comment: As a follow up, it looks like the picker is being rendered purely through CSS and it is the jquery that is failing. I tried to add the jquery straight to the html via <script> with no improvement. I checked my vendor.js and the datepicker js file has been compiled correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the existing addon for this?  https://github.com/soulim/ember-cli-bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: I did see that and I think it will be a great solution but it is still quite new and has a number of outstanding issues. I get problems integrating third party items like this quite often so I was looking to learn how it can be achieved when an ember add on isn't available